# How to initialize knockoutjs view model with .ajax data

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

The following code works great with a hardcoded array (initialData1), however I need to use jquery .ajax (initialData) to initialize the model and when I do the model shows empty:

```
    $(function () {

        function wiTemplateInit(winame, description) {
            this.WIName = winame
            this.WIDescription = description
        }

        var initialData = new Array;

        var initialData1 = [
            { WIName: "WI1", WIDescription: "WIDescription1" },
            { WIName: "WI1", WIDescription: "WIDescription1" },
            { WIName: "WI1", WIDescription: "WIDescription1" },
        ];
        console.log('gridrows:', initialData1);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{UserKey: '10'}",
            url: "WIWeb.asmx/GetTemplates",
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    initialData.push(new wiTemplateInit(data.d[i].WiName,data.d[i].Description));
                }
                //console.log('gridrows:', initialData);
                console.log('gridrows:', initialData);
            }
        });

        var viewModel = function (iData) {   
            this.wiTemplates = ko.observableArray(iData);

        };

        ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(initialData));

    });
```

I have been trying to work from the examples on the knockoutjs website, however most all the examples show hardcoded data being passed to the view model.

Comment: Have you debugged the network transmission to see what comes back? Check to see if anything comes back. If it does, what shape is the data? Is it the same as your hard coded date? Is there an error?

Comment: "however most all the examples show hardcoded data being passed to the view model". Are you [sure about that?](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html)

Comment: John-I debugged and checked the array with console.log, the data is getting to the client. Both arrays are same syntax with no errors.

Comment: sub- been there, I just didn't find those examples useful since they are not shown with any UI or model flow complexity.

Answer (score 7):

make sure your "WIWeb.asmx/GetTemplates" returns json array of objects with exact structure {WIName : '',WIDescription :''} 
and try using something like this

```
    function wiTemplateInit(winame, description)
    {
        var self = this;
        self.WIName = winame;
        self.WIDescription = description;
    }

    function ViewModel()
    {
        var self = this;
        self.wiTemplates = ko.observableArray();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{UserKey: '10'}",
            url: "WIWeb.asmx/GetTemplates",
            success: function (data)
            {
                var mappedTemplates = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new wiTemplateInit(item.WiName, item.Description) });
                self.wiTemplates(mappedTemplates);

            }
        });
    }

    var vm = new ViewModel();

    ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: could you do this with multiple $.ajax trips to be done in the same view model, ie say you had 2 self. variables that had to be retrieved seperately.

Comment: I swapped out the need for an actual item model and used `return ko.mapping.fromJS(item)` for each item in the $.map. Which gives you a dynamic feel

Comment: the use of ko.mapping.fromJS in the $.map function is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If you show us your browser log we can say more about your problem ( Especially post and response ). I prepared you a simple example to show how you can load data with ajax , bind template , manipulate them with actions and save it.

Hope this'll help to fix your issue :  http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/KbrHX/

Summary :

```
 // This is our item model 
function Item(id, name) {
   this.id = ko.observable(id);
   this.name = ko.observable(name);
}

// Initial Data . This will send to server and echo back us again
var data = [new Item(1, 'One'),
            new Item(2, 'Two'),
            new Item(3, 'Three'),
            new Item(4, 'Four'),
            new Item(5, 'Five')]

// This is a sub model. You can encapsulate your items in this and write actions in it
var ListModel = function() {    

   var self = this;    
   this.items  = ko.observableArray();
   this.remove = function(data, parent) {
        self.items.remove(data);
   };
   this.add    = function() {
        self.items.push(new Item(6, "Six"));
   };
   this.test   = function(data, e) {
       console.log(data);
       console.log(data.name());
   };
   this.save   = function() {        
       console.log(ko.mapping.toJSON(self.items));
   };   
}

// Here our viewModel only contains an empty listModel
function ViewModel() {
    this.listModel = new ListModel();
};

var viewModel = new ViewModel();

$(function() {
    $.post("/echo/json/", {
        // Data send to server and echo back
        json: $.toJSON(ko.mapping.toJS(data))
    }, function(data) {

    // Used mapping plugin to bind server result into listModel
    // I suspect that your server result may contain JSON string then 
    // just change your code into this
    // viewModel.listModel.items = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data); 

    viewModel.listModel.items = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
})
```